# App.open() sikuli is not working

Tags: java, testng, sikuli

I am new to sikuli, I am trying to use the sikuli API in eclipse, so I implemented the `App` class to use the open method, here how is my code look like

```
App.open( "C:\\java\\text.txt" );
```

but it says

```
file can't be found
```

but the file is actually exist. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for the function you are calling? http://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.org/en/latest/appclass.html#open-close-and-focus-an-application

Comment: i am following the documentation exactly, the thing is that the App.open("Skype.exe"); is working find but when specifying something else it doesn't find it

Comment: What about an absolute path to an executable? Perhaps the Sikuli api checks to find a file it can execute. `'text.txt'` not being one, it says `file can't be found.`

Comment: do you guys know whether the application must be open on my pc before i call the app.open method?

Answer (score 2):

`App.open` assumes that you provide an application as parameter, not a file.
See http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html#App
if you want to open this file with, for example Notepad++, you can do it like following (adapt it to your paths):

```
App.open("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe c:\\Temp\test.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation form Sikuli says your code should work, but for me that code wasn't working eather. 
I solved it by putting an r in front of the path.

```
# Path to Firefox executable: 
PathFirefox = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
# Open Firefox 
App.open(PathFirefox)
```

What the r does is, it converts something to a string. So it will take the backslash and quotes as part of the word/sentence.

Here is some documentation about my solution: [Link](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+faq/1739)